# Open a fancybox gallery from another HTML file

Tags: php, javascript, html, fancybox

I have two files, one with HTML code when I've diferent photo albums links, example:

```
<a href="albumprueba.php"><img class="fancyboxi"
 src="Libro Fez/Libro Fez - 001.jpg" alt="image19"
 width="91%" height="56" /></a>
```

And another file (is php) I've a routine that scans all the photos in a folder, and shows photos:

```
 <a  class="fancyboxi" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Laurea"
 href="Libro Fez/<?php echo $archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>"><img  
 src="Libro Fez/<?php echo $archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>" alt=""   width="19%"/></a>
```

I would like to open the HTML file from an album and open a fancybox with all the photos that showing the routine in PHP file.

I've tried to do in the  HTML file this, but doesn't works:

```
<a href="albumprueba.php?Libro Fez/Libro Fez - 001.jpg"><img src="Libro Fez/Libro Fez - 001.jpg" alt="image19" width="91%" height="56" /></a>
```

Any idea? thank.

Answer (score 0):

Your href is certainly malformed.

> albumprueba.php?Libro Fez/Libro Fez - 001.jpg

That isn't an address as URLs cannot have spaces (go to it manually and check what the address is in the navigation bar in your browser). Moreover it's just landing on a jpeg - are you sure you want this link to be to a single image?

Other than that the anchor *should* work. Are you getting a 404 error after following the link? If you want the other html file to be perptually viewable from the parent page you should consider using an iframe.

Comment: Yes, is an URL I check this adress in the navigator and is a single image. and i don't get a 404 error, the borwser shows albumprueba.php